# Xamarin Forms Command not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using the following fabmenu: https://github.com/Polarts/CrossFAB

Now I want to bind a command to the fabmenu buttons, so I did the following in page1.xaml:

```
<c:FloatingMenu Margin="0, 0, 10, 10" BGColor="#56D7A5" OpenIcon="openFab_icon" CloseIcon="closeFab_icon"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
    <c:FloatingButton x:Name="page1" BGColor="#59E1FF" IconSrc="page1" OnClickCommand="{Binding btnPage2Command}" />
</c:FloatingMenu>
```

And in page1.xaml.cs I did the following:

```
public partial class page1 : ContentPage
{

    public ICommand btnPage2Command{ get; set; }

    public page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnPage2Command= new Command(OpenPage2);
    }

    private async void OpenPage2()
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new page2());
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'OnClickCommand',
> or mismatching type between value and property.

### UPDATE:

I have now added the BindingContext, but I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at this line in the FloatingButton.xaml.cs (see https://github.com/Polarts/CrossFAB):

```
OnClickCommand.Execute(null);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Binding Context. Therefore you can assign it in the constructor or the xaml file.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
....
             x:Name="this">
```

And there you want to use it

```
<c:FloatingMenu Margin="0, 0, 10, 10" BGColor="#56D7A5" OpenIcon="openFab_icon" CloseIcon="closeFab_icon"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
    <c:FloatingButton BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" x:Name="page1" BGColor="#59E1FF" IconSrc="page1" OnClickCommand="{Binding btnPage2Command}" />
</c:FloatingMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it crashes in FloatingButton.xaml.cs with the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on this line: OnClickCommand.Execute(null);... Can you please take a look at the provided link? I have provided a command right? Why is it not executing?

Comment: Well, I m guessing because the sample you provided did not run on my emulators. So one of the problems could be the function you assign to the command. There should be at least `COMMANDNAME(object obj)`  object in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning a `BindingContext`

```
this.BindingContext = this;
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I crashes in FloatingButton.xaml.cs with the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line: `OnClickCommand.Execute(null);`... Can you please take a look at the provided link? I have provided a command right? Why is it not executing?

Comment: your Command has a string parameter but there is no CommandParameter defined in your XAML

Comment: What do I need to do with that paramter in XAML?

Comment: `OpenPage2` doesn't accept a parameter so I have no idea why you added it in the first place

Comment: It was already there when I used the code, the github link isn't mine. I just want to use it

Comment: But do I need to remove the extraCommand everywhere?